# How to disable upcoming dates in Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to disable upcoming dates in Bootstrap datepicker.

I have read some of the questions already for disabling dates in the past, and tried the below code

```
$('.date_time_picker .date_disp input').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            startDate:'-0d' // this prevents dates from yesterday
});
```

How can we disable future / upcoming dates and want to show only dates from this year.

So I should have the visible date ranges should be from 2018-01-01 to current date (2018-05-15)

Comment: The bootstrap datepicker has [`startdate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) and [`enddate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate) properties.

Comment: thank you, I should tried enddate when startdate is there

Answer (score 3):

To disable future dates try below code:

```
$('.date_time_picker .date_disp input').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            startDate:'-0d' // this prevents dates from yesterday
     endDate: '+0d' //this prevents dates from future being enabled to be selected

});
```

**endDate: '+0d'**  is what you need